# KDE allow window-change at password prompt

Tags: kde, password, configuration

When a certain password is neeeded, KDE spawns a Password-Prompt which blocks changing windows or doing anything outside the password-prompt itself. I have my passwords saved in Keepass, so I need to access keepass to copy my password from there and paste it into the password-prompt.

How can I change the password-prompt to not block any outside activity?

I would also be fine with solutions that replace the popup-window with an in-terminal password-input like the one in the Gnome-terminal, since that would effectively also solve the problem.

Comment: This is by design and protects you from some attack vectors. A behavioral solution is copying the password prior to enabling the popup. I know this is not the solution you are looking for, hence only a comment.

Comment: @Bruni I currently do it like this, however, in some situations (which I haven't figured out yet) the clipboard gets lost on the way. Also there might sometimes be an unexpected password-popup in which case I have to cancel and potentially start a long process again.

Comment: I used to have the same problem. For most system password popups, I use kde wallet now. This of course is no solution, if you share your computer.